# How to show pop up in Flutter app lunch state?

Tags: flutter

I want to show version update alert box on home page every time the user launch the app.
I currently implemented the alert box in the initState() of the home page. However when I go to another screen and come back to home screen the alert box show up since the initState() is called.

I only want to show the alert box in the start of application.I don't want to show after going to another screen and comeback. Which call back is available for that.

Comment: You can probably use Shared Preferences, by setting the value to true if the popup was showed, then resetting on application quit. https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/shared_preferences

Comment: Yea. But how do I know when the application quit? Is there any call back method like initState()?

Comment: you can look here, this might help https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19594

Answer (score 0):

```dart
class HomeState extends State<Home> {
    alertShown = false;

    @override    
    void initState() {
        if (!alertShown) {
            // Show your dialog here
            // ...

            alertShown = true;
        }
    }
}
```